# How can send email to two email Id's in Mail function

Tags: php, email

**This is my code**

```
$secondEmail="eamail2@gmail.com";
```

**to send mail two emails**

```
$to = $email,$secondEmail;
$email_from = 'website.com';
$email_subject = "Register Details: " ;
$email_body = "Sender Name: $from"
```

.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mail ids as string,

```
$to = $email.",".$secondEmail;
$email_from = 'website.com';
$email_subject = "Register Details: " ;
$email_body = "Sender Name: $from"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple emails `With comma separated` values

```
$to = "myfirstemail@xyz.com, mysecondemail@xyz.com";
$email_from = 'website.com';
$email_subject = "Register Details: " ;
$email_body = "Sender Name: $from" ;
```

For variable simply put it in `""`;

```
$email1="eamil1@gmail.com";
$email2="email2@gmail.com";
$to = "$email1 , $email2";
```

Comment: if email address in variables then?Like $email1="eamil1@gmail.com",and $email2="email2@gmail.com"

Comment: Use comma as string in separation of two email variables @rahul